# How to render in R stats each node in igraph using a BASE64 string

Tags: r, igraph

[I have the following table](https://norwayanalytics-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/pl_norwayanalytics_no/Edt9PKCS281Js4JbQnQVH6cBmiLmrpG9deZOTbeHxlTheQ?e=EG75qy)
[image]

I need to render a network using Igraph, with each node representing the person involved in the project. (for this purpose I used a rubber duck in a very low resolution)

[image]

As you can see right now, at each node in rendering just the "Work Item" but I need to render a string containing a Base 64 jpeg.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dataset, directed=TRUE)
ceb <- cluster_edge_betweenness(g) 
plot(ceb, g, vertex.label.cex=.5)
```

Comment: We need `dataset` to reproduce your code; please use `dput` to include sample data.

Comment: Hi, Have you click in the "I have the following table" hyperlink? You should be able to download the file.

Comment: Data should not be stored on an external site (links break over time). The question should be self-sufficient. See [how to share data in a reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). So you want the actual image encoded in the image_with_prefix column to be drawn in the center of the circles?

Comment: Correct, what I need is the image drawn at the nodes.
About reproducible format, not even one Base64 string will fit on the allow space for comments or description. 

Below DPUT() outout without string B64.

structure(list(`Work Item Id` = c(141958, 141959, 141961, 141962, 
141963, 142286), `Parent Work Item Id` = c(141957, 141957, 141957, 
141957, 141957, 141968)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))